# Any idea why i'm getting these two errors in my c++ program?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm writing a program that creates a complex number class and I am getting these two errors when i try to test my overloaded operator >>. Here are the errors:

> error LNK2028: unresolved token
>   (0A0002BD) "class
>   std::basic_istream > & __cdecl
>   operator>>(class
>   std::basic_istream > &,class
>   Complex const &)"
>   (??5@$$FYAAAV?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@ABVComplex@@@Z)
>   referenced in function "int __cdecl
>   main(void)" (?main@@$$HYAHXZ)
>
> error LNK2019: unresolved external
>   symbol "class
>   std::basic_istream > & __cdecl
>   operator>>(class
>   std::basic_istream > &,class
>   Complex const &)"
>   (??5@$$FYAAAV?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@ABVComplex@@@Z)
>   referenced in function "int __cdecl
>   main(void)" (?main@@$$HYAHXZ)

Here is my overload function:

```
istream& operator >> (istream& in, Complex& a){
    double real, imaginary;
    in >> real >> imaginary;
    a.setReal(real);
    a.setImaginary(imaginary);  
    return in;
}
```

Also it says its coming from my mainComplex.obj, mainComplex is a cpp file that has the main function i use to test the program.

```
int main(){     
    Complex num;
    cout << "Enter Complex number: ";
    cin >> num;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler, when processing `main` has found that the best overload for the expression `cin >> num;` is `std::basic_istream<...>& operator>>( std::basic_istream<...>&, const Complex& )`, note the `const` in the second argument.

This probably indicates that you have declared the operator as:

```
std::istream& operator>>( std::istream&, const Complex & );
```

But then implemented:

```
std::istream& operator>>( std::istream&, Complex & );
```

Comment: Ah yes! It compiles and works! Thank you very much! I guess i just overlooked that const in the declaration.

Comment: Error strings are not the simplest to read, but they contain information on what the compiler/linker are interpreting from your code, and that does help catching errors.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have implemented the `>>` operator as a member of your class when really it needs to be a `friend` in order to use it in the way you intend.

Have a look at this SO question: [Should operator<< be implemented as a friend or as a member function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236801/should-operator-be-implemented-as-a-friend-or-as-a-member-function)

There is also a section on these operators in Scott Meyers: Effective C++ Programming but I don't have the book to hand to give a reference.

Comment: My overloaded operators are all declared as friend functions in my Complex class not as member functions.

Comment: In which case could it be you are trying to read from `cin` within your function, rather than from the istream parameter `in`: `cin >> real >> imaginary;` should that line be `in >> real >> imaginary;`

Comment: Thanks for catching that, but it still gives me the same errors when I compile.