# QT: Error Overloading the "<<" operator in Qdatastream

Tags: qt, qt4

I have a class

```
class budget
{
    float transportation, grocery, food, stationery;
    QString key;
public:
//input output functions here.

};
```

I created a QHash> and << operators for my class.

```
QDataStream &operator <<(QDataStream &stream, budget &myclass)
{
    stream<<myclass.getFood();
    stream<<myclass.getGrocery();
    stream<<myclass.getKey();
    stream<<myclass.getStatn();
    stream<<myclass.getTransport();

    return stream;
}

QDataStream &operator >>(QDataStream &stream, budget &myclass)
{
    float f;
    QString s;
    stream>>f;
    myclass.addFood(f);
    stream>>f;
    myclass.addGrocery(f);
    stream>>s;
    myclass.addDate(s);
    stream>>f;
    myclass.addStatn(f);
    stream>>f;
    myclass.addTransport(f);

    return stream;
}
```

But even now i still get an error:

> C:\Users\Karthik\QT\Mendrive-build-simulator-Simulator_Qt_for_MinGW_4_4__Qt_SDK__Debug........\QtSDK\Simulator\Qt\mingw\include\QtCore\qdatastream.h:381:
>   **error: no match for 'operator<<' in
>   'operator<<(((QDataStream&)((QDataStream*)out)), ((const
>   QString&)((const QString*)it.QHash::const_iterator::key with
>   Key = QString, T = budget))) << it.QHash::const_iterator::value with Key = QString, T = budget'**

Why is this happening? Apparently the >> operator seems to be overloaded i get the error only for the << operator.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error stems from the declaration of the function signatures. Change your declarations from:

```
QDataStream &operator <<(QDataStream &stream, budget &myclass);
QDataStream &operator >>(QDataStream &stream, budget &myclass);
```

to:

```
QDataStream &operator <<(QDataStream &stream, const budget &myclass);
QDataStream &operator >>(QDataStream &stream, budget &myclass);
```

The same problem has described [here](http://www.qtforum.org/article/3243/qdatastream-overload-and.html)

Sorry I have missed one thing. Methods must be declares as friends also. So I have tried it out and here is working result;

```
class budget
{
  float transportation, grocery, food, stationery;
  QString key;
public:
  budget() {}

friend QDataStream &operator <<(QDataStream &stream, const budget &myclass) {

      stream<< myclass.food;
      stream<< myclass.grocery;
      stream<< myclass.key;
      stream<< myclass.stationery;
      stream<< myclass.transportation;

    return stream;

}
friend QDataStream &operator >>(QDataStream &stream, budget &myclass) {

    stream >> myclass.food;
    stream >> myclass.grocery;
    stream >> myclass.key;
    stream >> myclass.stationery;
    stream >> myclass.transportation;
    return stream;

}
```

**update**

To answer your question regarding friend functions let me point you to the answer already available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236801/should-operator-be-implemented-as-a-friend-or-as-a-member-function)

Comment: I tried the solution above in the beginning, but that lead to 5 errors of the form:
`C:\Users\Karthik\QT\Mendrive-build-simulator-Simulator_Qt_for_MinGW_4_4__Qt_SDK__Debug\..\Mendrive\fileoverload.h:11: error: passing 'const budget' as 'this' argument of 'float budget::**getFood()**' discards qualifiers`
Where **getFood()** is replaced by by other member functions. That's why i tried removing the `const`

Comment: yea thats because the funcs have to return const values.

Comment: Yes! The declaring it as a friend function did it! Could you please explain though, how it made a difference? I still can't understand why it wasn't working as a non-friend function. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You really should learn how to use 'const', look up a tutorial somewhere and read it. Maybe this http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html . change your "float budget::getFood();" method to "float budget::getFood() const;"