# Significance of overloading operator - () as free function & not a member function?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I was reading [the C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/operator-overloading.html). There I found a point in the guideline for operator overloading uses:

> If you provide constructive operators, they should allow promotion of the left-hand operand (at least in the case where the class has a single-parameter ctor that is not marked with the explicit keyword). For example, if your class Fraction supports promotion from int to Fraction (via the non-explicit ctor Fraction::Fraction(int)), and if you allow x - y for two Fraction objects, you should also allow 42 - y. **In practice that simply means that your operator-() should not be a member function of Fraction. Typically you will make it a friend, if for no other reason than to force it into the public: part of the class, but even if it is not a friend, it should not be a member.**

Why has the author written that operator-() should not be member function?

What are the bad consequences if I make operator-() as member function and what are other consequences?

Comment: Note that the title is wrong: `operator()` cannot be implemented as a free function. Most operators can, but not all. The quote deals with `operator-`, not `operator()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should operator<< be implemented as a friend or as a member function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236801/should-operator-be-implemented-as-a-friend-or-as-a-member-function)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is `Fraction` with the operator as a member function:

```
class Fraction
{
    Fraction(int){...}

    Fraction operator -( Fraction const& right ) const { ... }
};
```

With it, this is valid code:

```
Fraction x;
Fraction y = x - 42;
```

and its equivalent to `x.operator-( Fraction(42) )`; but this is not:

```
Fraction z = 42 - x;
```

Because `42` has no member function `operator -` in it *(of course, its not even a class)*.

However, if you declare your operator as a free function instead, conversion operations apply to both of its arguments. So this

```
Fraction z = 42 - x;
```

turns into this

```
Fraction z = Fraction(42) - x;
```

which is equivalent to `operator-( Fraction(42), x )`.

Comment: ...can you please elaborate the meaning of free function here ? Do you mean to say friend function ?

Comment: @Abhishek Gupta: No, I meant to say _free function_. A _free function_ is a function at a namespace scope, that is the opposite of a _member function_.

Comment: Also please tell me what is the meaning of constructive operators ?

Comment: All operators which result in constructing a new object. In this case the '-' operator for example.