# How to overload the output and input operator?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

**This is a topic is covered in a generalized way in another post that i found later: [Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)**

But to be specific, here is a small snippet of code:

```
class wordchecklist
{
    string name,type;
    unsigned int stats;
};
```

What i want to do, is overload the output operator so that the following code works

**Edit:** (keep in mind it contains **private** members so i would prefer doing so by creating a member function of some sort):

```
ofstream data(database.txt,ios::app);
data<<wordchecklist;
data.close();
```

so that my database.txt file contains:

*mywordchecklistname mywordchecklisttype mywordcheckliststats*

Same goes for the input operator...

Comment: You might looking for something related to http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/93-overloading-the-io-operators

Answer (score 3):

You have to define a non-member function:

```
std::ofstream &operator <<(std::ofstream &stream, const wordchecklist &data)
{
     stream << data.name << " " << data.type << " " << data.stats << std::endl;
     return stream;
}
```

Do the same for `::operator >>`.

ProTip: use `CamelCaps` or `under_scores` in identifiers in order your classes to have a readable name.

Comment: First, it's a more or less established convention to put the `>>` and the `<<` operators in the same namespace as the user defined type.  It may be the global namespace here, but that's certainly not always the case, as your comment "Do the same for `::operator>>` would suggest.

Comment: And of course, `operator>>` is generally an order of magnitude more difficult than `operator<<`.  Something you should think about in `operator<<`: what happens, for example, if `wordchecklist::name` can contain spaces.

Comment: @JamesKanze 1. Right. But what if we interpret `::operator >>` as an operator in whatever namespace this is in? 2. If we assume that the input file format is the same as the one `operator<<` outputs, then one can simply use `std::getline()` to read one line then parse it.

Comment: I edited the question: How to handle private data members then?

Comment: `std::getline` won't work unless his `<<` operator always outputs a full line, including the trailing `'\n'`.  This is not the usual convention.  And you'd still have to parse the line you read.  Anytime you output strings, you must establish some sort of convention it order to delimit them.  In the simplest case, the strings cannot contain spaces, and your code would work; but most of the time, you'll need some sort of delimiters, or something to ensure that you can find the end of each string.

Comment: @reubenjohn I believe you can `friend` it, do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236801/should-operator-be-implemented-as-a-friend-or-as-a-member-function).

Comment: @JamesKanze "unless his `<<` operator always outputs a full line" - isn't that **exactly** what his requirement ("mywordchecklistname mywordchecklisttype mywordcheckliststats") suggests?

Comment: @H2CO3 Not really.  And your `operator<<` doesn't output a new line.  But as an example, how would you write and read `wordchecklist data[2] = { { "James A.", "Kanze", 42 }, { "James", "A. Kanze", 24 } };`?  There's a lot more work upfront if you want to do IO correctly.  (Admittedly, that wasn't his question, and maybe he realizes this.  But IMHO, it's worth at least mentioning.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Appended an `std::endl` so that the operator outputs a new line. As to what to do with an array: `std::for_each(data, data + 2, [](const T &arg) { stream << arg; });`

Comment: @H2CO3 The code you posted still doesn't work with the input I gave.

Comment: @JamesKanze Excuse me, but isn't that a bit arbitrary complaint? Show your input, show what format **exactly** it is in (but wait, wouldn't it be enough if the code works with whatever input OP has!?), then I have the chance to adapt the code.

Comment: @H2CO3 It's not a complaint, it's a fact.  I posted an example of data that cannot be reread correctly if written by your code.  Try it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34308/discussion-between-h2co3-and-james-kanze)