# Writing a struct into a stringstream in C++

Tags: c++, stringstream

I have some structs as:

```
struct dHeader
{
    uint8_t    blockID;
    uint32_t   blockLen;
    uint32_t   bodyNum;
};
struct dBody
{
    char       namestr[10];
    uint8_t    blk_version;
    uint32_t   reserved1;
}
```

and I have a stringstream as:

```
std::stringstream Buffer(std::iostream::in | std::iostream::out);
```

I want to write a dHdr and multiple dBody structs into Buffer with

```
Buffer << Hdr1;
Buffer << Body1;
Buffer << Body1;
```

I get the error:

> error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'Buffer << Hdr1'

If I try it with:

```
Buffer.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&Hdr1), sizeof(dbHdr1));
Buffer.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&Body1), sizeof(Body1));
Buffer.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&Body2), sizeof(Body2));
```

I get confused about the packing and memory alignment.

- **What is the best way to write a struct into a stringstream?**
- **And read
  the stringstream into a regular string?**

Comment: read about `serialization`, you want to serialize the struct . There is also a boost library for that http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html ( along others )

Comment: there are a couple things you need to think about: do you want something human readable, or just machine readable (the latter tends to be more concise and faster to pack/parse)? for binary streams, do you need something in the stream to let the unpacking side know what's been packed, or will the contents be predictable?

Comment: The resulting string will be downloaded on a card, thus it does not need to be human readable.

Comment: Won't overloading operator '<<' work here?

Comment: @mustafa, the error message (no match for operator...) states exactly that you didn't overload `operator<<`. See my answer below.

Comment: thanks @utnapistim what about `Buffer.write`? wouldn't it be easier?

Comment: @mustafa, I will edit my answer below (easier that writing this in a comment).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For each of your structures, you need to define something similar to this:

```
struct dHeader
{
    uint8_t    blockID;
    uint32_t   blockLen;
    uint32_t   bodyNum;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const dHeader& h)
{
     return out << h.blockID << " " << h.blockLen << " " << h.bodyNum;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, dHeader& h) // non-const h
{
    dHeader values; // use extra instance, for setting result transactionally
    bool read_ok = (in >> values.blockID >> values.blockLen >> values.bodyNum);

    if(read_ok /* todo: add here any validation of data in values */)
        h = std::move(values);
    /* note: this part is only necessary if you add extra validation above
    else
        in.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit); */
    return in;
}
```

(similar for the other structures).

**Edit:** An un-buffered read/write implementation has the following drawbacks:

- it is unformatted; This may not be an issue for a small utility application, if you control where it is compiled and run, but normally, if you take the serialized data and run/compile the app on a different architecture you will have issues with endianness; you will also need to ensure the types you use are not-architecture dependent (i.e. keep using `uintXX_t` types).
- it is brittle; The implementation depends on the structures only containing POD types. If you add a char* to your structure later, your code will compile the same, just expose undefined behavior.
- it is obscure (clients of your code would expect to either see an interface defined for I/O or assume that your structures support no serialization). Normally, nobody thinks "maybe I *can* serialize, but using un-buffered I/O" - at least not when being the client of a custom struct or class implementation.

The issues *can* be ameliorated, by adding i/o stream operators, implemented in terms of un-buffered reads and writes.

Example code for the operators above:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const dHeader& h)
{
     out.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&h), sizeof(dHeader));
     return out;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, dHeader& h) // non-const h
{
    dHeader values; // use extra instance, for setting result transactionally
    bool read_ok = in.read( reinterpret_cast<char*>(&values), sizeof(dHeader) );

    if(read_ok /* todo: add here any validation of data in values */)
        h = std::move(values);
    /* note: this part is only necessary if you add extra validation above
    else
        in.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit); */
    return in;
}
```

This centralizes the code behind an interface (i.e. if your class no longer supports un-buffered writes, you will have to change code in *one* place), and makes your intent obvious (implement serialization for your structure). It is still brittle, but less so.

Comment: Yes. You would write a char* (converted from struct) and read a char* converted from struct.

Comment: can you please add it to your answer too?

Comment: @mustafa, I have editted the code to also contain an un-buffered read implementation for the input operator.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide an overload for `std::ostream::operator<<` like

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const dHeader&);
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const dBody&);
```

For more information see this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236801/should-operator-be-implemented-as-a-friend-or-as-a-member-function).