# What happens if there's an 'overloading clash' regarding streams?

Tags: c++, stream, operator-overloading

Suppose we had an `istream` subclass with the following method:

```
SomeStream& operator>>(Something& something) {
    // .. write data into something
}
```

And we also had the following global method:

```
Something& operator>>(istream& stream, Something& something) {
    // .. write data from stream into something
}
```

How does C++ know which method to call for the following code:

```
instanceOfSomeStream >> instanceOfSomething;
```

---

Follow up question: what is the better or more common way to allow a `SomeStream` to be written into a `Something` - should I add another overload for `operator>>` in `SomeStream`, that takes a `Something&` argument? Or should I go the opposite way, and create an overload in `Something` that takes a `SomeStream`? (Actually not in `Something`, but as a global function because of obvious reasons).

Comment: Normally when you entend an `std::istream` or `std::ostream`, you do it for the purpose of wrapping a custom `std::streambuf`. If you need to provide I/O functionality for a type, do it by overloading the global `operator>>()`/`operator<<()` like in the second code block. Any custom behavior `SomeStream` may exhibit should be related to the buffer that it may use, otherwise it's not worth creating another stream type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ has complicated overload resolution rules in general. In this case it's useful to know that a member function, for the purposes of overload resolution, behaves like a non-member function that takes a reference to the class as an implied first argument, *i.e.*, the choice is between something like [1]

```
SomeStream& operator>>(SomeStream& somestream, Something& something)
```

and

```
Something& operator>>(istream& stream, Something& something)
```

Of course the return type doesn't matter, and for

```
instanceOfSomeStream >> instanceOfSomething
```

the first overload will be chosen because `SomeStream` is more derived than `istream`.

Your follow-up question should be a separate question. There's some discussion here which might be related: [Should operator<< be implemented as a friend or as a member function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236801/should-operator-be-implemented-as-a-friend-or-as-a-member-function)

[1] Note: I say "something like" because this is not exactly correct. For example such a member function can be called on an rvalue object expression even though an lvalue reference is shown above.

Comment: There are a number of differences between the implicit parameter and a reference you might declare yourself. And, the answer to the linked question is emphatically that it must be a free function. `istream` should never be subclassed except for something like `istringstream` of `ifstream`, i.e. to support a `streambuf` subclass.