# which "<<" operator function should be used?

Tags: c++, friend

There are two ways of implementing operator "<<" or ">>" function in a project.

1.As a non-member function

2.As a friend

```
  #include<iostream>
  using namespace std;
  class xxx{
     private: int x;
     public: xxx(int val=0):x(val){}
              int getx(){return x;}
             friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& o, xxx& x1);
  };
  ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, xxx& x1)
  {
    o<<x1.getx();
    return o;
  }
  ostream& operator <<(ostream& o, xxx& x1)
  {
     o<<x1.getx();
     return o;
  }
  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
     xxx x1(5);
     return 0;
  }
```

Looks like both non-member and friend function have same signature when implementing, and thus i get compiler error :
"error: redefinition of 'std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, xxx&)' ".

Could anyone please help how to compile the above code.

Also would like to know in which situation should we use non-member "operator =" function over friend "operator =" function.

Comment: If you declare a friend-function then it's really a non-member function as well.

Comment: Make it a friend if it needs to be one.

Comment: `operator =` can't be a non-member or friend; it has to be a member.

Comment: @AlanStokes: if you make it as member function then you have to write like this x1<<o; instead of o<<x1.getx(), which will make the statement different.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should operator<< be implemented as a friend or as a member function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236801/should-operator-be-implemented-as-a-friend-or-as-a-member-function)

Comment: @Santosh True, but not relevant to either of my comments.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confused -- a friend function *is* a non-member function.  So your `friend` declaration declares the non-member function and makes it a friend.  You then define the (non-member) function twice, which is an error.

The two ways to define (most) overloaded operators is as a *member* function or a non-member function.  You cannot do both for the same operator, and if you define it as a non-member, it may be a friend or not as you prefer (`friend` is irrelevant)

As for your final question -- you cannot define `operator=` as a non-member function.  It *must* be a member function.  `friend` is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

The two definitions are identical. And in your case, the operator is not accessing private or protected members of the class, so the friend declaration is redundant.