# Difference between << / >> operator overloading and Input/Output functions

Tags: c++

I would really appreciate if someone could explain to me the difference between overloading the input/output operators, for example:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& ost, const myClass& obj) {
    return ost << obj.x << obj.y;
}
```

and Output/Input functions like these:

```
void Output(ostream& ost) {
    ost << x << y;
}
```

What are they used for, examples etc. Everything is acceptable. Thanks!

Comment: Not much different really. The `operator<<` is called when you write `ost << obj`. That's about it - it creates a nicer(?) syntax and enables chaining, so you can output more than one thing at a time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overloading the `<<` operator will allow you to chain output operations:

```
myClass a, b;

...

cout << a << ' ' << b;
```

Using your alternate implementation, you would have to write:

```
myClass a, b;

...

a.Output(cout);
cout << ' ';
a.Output(b);
```

The first version makes it easier to quickly see how the output will be formatted. It is also the standard way to use streams in C++.

Answer (score 4):

The main difference is that if you overload "stream operators" then your classes can be used by template functions.

Using a standard-named output method would have worked similarly but using the stream operator has the added advantage that it can be defined for non-class types too (i.e. you can define what it means to output an integer to a stream, but you cannot define the method `.output` for an integer).

Answer (score 3):

The operator<< is used if you want to call it thus:  `cout << myObject`
...and Output there can be used if you wanted to call it thus:  `myObject.Output(cout);` (but, who would?).

But I suspect what you've got going on here is two competing ways of writing the << operator.

The first is the one above, with the `friend` keyword.

Here's another version:

```
void myClass::Output (ostream& ost)
{
    ost << x << y;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& ost, const myClass& obj) 
{
    obj.Output (ost); return ost;
}
```

The second version is generally considered better, because it avoids the use of `friend`, which is considered a security risk.  Allowing non-member functions to access the private section (so the reasoning goes) reduces the security of that private section.

Here's a stack overflow article that discusses this at greater length:
[Should operator<< be implemented as a friend or as a member function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236801/should-operator-be-implemented-as-a-friend-or-as-a-member-function)

...and the general philosophy of "when to use friend" is discussed here:  https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/105766/c-to-friend-or-not-to-friend

My take on this is that it is not evil to use `friend`, but I avoid it when it's not needed.  And here, it is not, as the second version shows.

Comment: This answer would benefit from a rationale for the "security violation" part.

Comment: I think "security violation" makes it sound far worse than it is. It's more of a security "special case". Not ideal, but not a catastrophe either :p

Comment: Yes.  I don't do it here, but it's not horrible.

Answer (score 1):

There is really no difference (from technical standpoint) between overloading any of those. As a matter of fact, even those are not special. They are simply overloadable operators - shift-left operator and shift-right operator. The reason to overload operators in general is to provide a better syntax, and the reason to overload those in particular is somewhat traditional based on perceived intuitivity.

Tradionally, `operator <<` is overloaded to *send* something into something else (and called *insertion operator*), and `operator >>` is overload to *extract* something from something else - and is referred to as *extraction operator*. In majority of cases, this *something* you are sending to is `output stream`, such as `std::cout`, and something you are extracting from is input stream, something like `std::cin`. Having this in mind, `std::cout << "Hello\n"` is easily understood as sending string "Hello\n" to output stream, which in case of `std::cout` usually has an effect of printing it on the console window.

However, one could absolutely swap those overloads, and overload >> as an insertion operator. In latter case, printing would take form of `std::cout >> "Hello\n"`. Wouldn't make any difference from compiler standpoint, but is less intuitive for programmers - those >> and << do resemble arrows.

Completely different operators could be chosen for this purpose. For instance, `->` is an overloadable operator too, and choosing it as an extraction operator would be great. Just consider this: `std::cin -> str`. Arrow is even more explicit. Unfortunately, there is no overloadable operator `<-`, so this lacks symmetry.

Also, one have to remember, that operator overloading was invented to allow C++ programms define new entities without introducing new reserved language constructs. If C++ was a completely fresh language, and would not stand on the shoulders of C, the end result would likely be very different.