# Do I really need to bend over backwards for a friend operator<< for a class in a namespace?

Tags: c++, private, encapsulation, friend

I want to implemnent an operator<<  for streaming my class (say it's named `Paragraph`). Class `Paragraph` has some private data, for which reason I want the (freestanding) operator<< function to be a friend. So, I do as suggested, e.g., [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/237074/1593077). `friend` statement, implement the `operator<<` and all is well.

But now I want to put Paragraph inside a namespace, say `namespace foo`. It no longer works! If I write:

```
namespace foo {
class Paragraph {
    public:
        explicit Paragraph(std::string const& init) :m_para(init) {}
        std::string const&  to_str() const { return m_para; }
    private:
        friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Paragraph& p);
        std::string     m_para;
};
} // namespace foo
```

The compiler tells me I've befriended `foo::operator<<`, not `::operator<<`. Ok, fair enough. So, I replace the friend line with:

```
    friend std::ostream & ::operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Paragraph& p);
```

but I get an error again (from GCC 5.4.0), telling me the `::operator<<` has not having been declared. Ok, let's declare it then. Will this work?:

```
namespace foo {
std::ostream & ::operator<<(std::ostream &os, const foo::Paragraph& p);
class Paragraph {
    public:
        explicit Paragraph(std::string const& init) :m_para(init) {}
        std::string const&  to_str() const { return m_para; }
    private:
        friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Paragraph& p);
        std::string     m_para;
};
} // namespace foo
```

Nope, it doesn't know about Paragraph when reading the declaration of `::operator<`. Ok, let's forward-declare:

```
namespace foo {
class Paragraph;
std::ostream & ::operator<<(std::ostream &os, const foo::Paragraph& p);
class Paragraph { /* actual definition here */ } }
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const foo::Paragraph& p) { /* impl */ }
```

no luck. I get the weird error:

```
f.cpp:23:16: note: candidate: std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const foo::Paragraph&)
 std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const foo::Paragraph& p)
                ^
f.cpp:11:15: note: candidate: std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const foo::Paragraph&)
 std::ostream& ::operator<<(std::ostream &os, const foo::Paragraph& p);
```

... and here I was thinking the global namespace and the :: namespace are the same thing... arent' they? (sigh). No matter, let's move the declaration out of the namespace:

```
class foo::Paragraph;
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const foo::Paragraph& p);
namespace foo { class Paragraph { /* actual definition here */ } }
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const foo::Paragraph& p) { /* impl */ }
```

Still not good enough, now I get the "'foo' has not been declared" error. (granshes teeth) fine! Be that way!

```
namespace foo { class Paragraph; }
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const foo::Paragraph& p);

namespace foo { class Paragraph { /* actual definition here */ } }
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const foo::Paragraph& p) { /* impl */ }
```

so this, but no less than this, works. That's *terrible*! Surely there must be some kind of less verbose way to do it... right?

**Note:** Assume the `operator<<` can't be inlined and must be defined separately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems your problem stems from not realizing how [ADL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111677/what-is-argument-dependent-lookup-aka-adl-or-koenig-lookup) can find the right `operator<<` as long as it is the same namespace as `Paragraph`. To expand on your first example

```
// this is what you have already
namespace foo {
class Paragraph {
 public:
  explicit Paragraph(std::string const& init) :m_para(init) {}
  std::string const&  to_str() const { return m_para; }
 private:
  friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Paragraph& p);
  std::string     m_para;
};
} // namespace foo

// Now we can add a definition here, or in a different TU
namespace foo {
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Paragraph& p) {
  return os << p.m_para;
}
} // namespace foo


int main() {
  foo::Paragraph p("hello");
  // finds your operator<< using adl
  std::cout << p << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Your first sentence hit the nail on the head. Or perhaps I should say my head.

Comment: @einpoklum Furthermore, this is the only solution that guarantees name lookup will succeed. `::operator<<` would not be found in some contexts, since it is not part of the ADL lookup set.

Answer (score 3):

Just put the definition of the `<<` operator in the namespace along with `Paragraph`. Argument-dependent lookup will find it when you insert a `Paragraph` object into a stream.

```
// myheader.h:
namespace ns {
    struct x {
        /* ... */
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const x&);
    };
}

// myheader.cpp:
#include "myheader.h"
namespace ns {
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const x& xx) {
        os << xx.whatever() << '\n';
        return os;
    }
}
```

Or, if it's small enough to warrant inlining, just do that:

```
// myheader.h:
namespace ns {
    struct x {
        /* ... */
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const x&);
    };
    inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const x& xx) {
        os << xx.whatever() << '\n';
        return os;
    }
}
```