# Overloading cout to see what is inside pointer

Tags: c++, overloading

This past month I am studying a lot of C++, and know I'm trying too practice a little, and for that I cloned the Electron project.

In the file `src/electron/atom/browser/api/atom_api_session.cc` there is this code:

```
  379 void Session::OnDownloadCreated(content::DownloadManager* manager,                                                                       
  380                                 content::DownloadItem* item) {                                                                           
  381   if (item->IsSavePackageDownload())                                                                                                     
  382     return;                                                                                                                              
  383                                                                                                                                          
  384   v8::Locker locker(isolate());                                                                                                          
  385   v8::HandleScope handle_scope(isolate());                                                                                               
  386   bool prevent_default = Emit(                                                                                                           
  387       "will-download",                                                                                                                   
  388       DownloadItem::Create(isolate(), item),                                                                                             
  389       item->GetWebContents());                                                                                                           
  390   if (prevent_default) {                                                                                                                 
  391     item->Cancel(true);                                                                                                                  
  392     item->Remove();                                                                                                                      
  393   }                                                                                                                                      
  394 }
```

I would like to print what is the manager with `stdout::cout << manager;`, so I created a function to overload the `<<` as the books told me:

```
  375 void operator << (std::ostream & o, const content::DownloadManager* manager) {                                                           
  376   o << "manager:" << manager;                                                                                                            
  377 }
```

But this isn't working at all.

Comment: you should return a stream, find some examples.

Comment: "this isn't working at all" - how is it not working? What happens and what is the expected output?

Comment: @jay The compiler fails

Comment: The return type should be `std::ostream&` (reference important, it has to be the same `ostream`)  and at the end of the function you should return `o`. If you don't do that the next call to `operator<<` will have no stream to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `content::DownloadManager*` looks like a pointer to a class instance. Simply doing `o << "manager:" << manager;` will not print the content of the class. You have to know the data members of `content::DownloadManager` to print them using `<<`operator overloading. However you will have to `return` `std::ostream` after updating it. For example look at the following example for overloading the `<<` `>>` operators.

```
struct Quote
{
  std::string ticker;
  std::string exchange;
  std::string full_name;
  double value;
  std::string data;
  long long timestampus;
  long long timestamps;

  friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, Quote& object)
  {
      out << object.ticker << " " << object.exchange << " " << object.full_name << " " << object.value << " " << object.data << " " <<  object.timestampus << " " << object.timestamps;
      return out;
  }

  friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, Quote& object)
  {
      in >> object.ticker;
      in >> object.exchange;
      in >> object.full_name;
      in >> object.value;
      in >> object.data;
      in >> object.timestampus;
      in >> object.timestamps;
      return in;
  }
};
```

Also take a look this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236801/should-operator-be-implemented-as-a-friend-or-as-a-member-function) to understand whether you wanna define that as a member or friend or non-friend. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! This was clarifying.