# C++ Overloading <<. Error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream' {aka 'std::basic_ostream<char>'} and 'Poly')

Tags: c++

Recently started to learn c++. Now i'm trying to overload << operator to print an instance of my class `Poly` representing polynomial. Here it is:

```
class Poly {
public:
    Poly(unsigned int n);
    Poly(Poly &obj);
    int& operator[] (int index);
    unsigned int degree();
    long eval(int x);
    Poly& operator= (Poly& p);


private:
    int *coeffs;
    unsigned int n;
};`
```

Implementations of methods work fine. I tried to define global function that overloads << operation :

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &os, Poly &p) {
    for (int i = 0; i < p.degree()+1; i++){
        if (i != 0)
            os << " + " << p[i] << "x^" << i;
        else
            os << p[i];
    }
    os << std::endl;
    return os;
}
```

but I get error in line where cout << p2 is in my main function:

```
int main() {
    Poly *p1 = new Poly(2);
    (*p1)[0] = 1;
    (*p1)[1] = 1;
    (*p1)[2] = 3;
    cout<< p1->eval(2) << endl;
    Poly p2(2);
    p2 = (*p1);

    cout << p2;

    return 0;
}
```

If I declare this function in the class declaration as a `friend` everything works. Is that really necessary as this function doesn't access private members of the class? What do I do wrong? Iostream included everywhere.

Comment: Looks like you are missing a declaration. Add `std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &os, Poly &p);` to your header file (outside of the class). Then any file including this header will also see the overload.

Comment: Most likely is that your code is missing a prototype for the `operator<<`. Adding a friend declaration also adds the missing prototype.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236801/should-operator-be-implemented-as-a-friend-or-as-a-member-function

Comment: @NeilGatenby `friend` is only needed if you need access to private members. In this case, `friend` declaration also works as a regular declaration (i.e. saying to the world "there is such a function somewhere"), so it fixes the issue. But having just a regular declaration should work as well.